# Split nodes with list into unique nodes and maintain their relationships

Tags: neo4j, cypher

My data model has 2 `Person` nodes connected to a `Form` node by a `HAS_FORMS` relationship. A `Form` node has a `names` property containing a list of names (e.g., `['solid', 'liquid','gas']` or `['solid','liquid','gel']`),  and I want to make it such that each value in `names` becomes a node by itself, along with the relevant  connections to the person node, and additionally I don't want any duplicates.

[image]

[image]

I tried adding a constraint after creating the nodes (with duplicates) and i tried to use `With distinct` when I used `unwind`. Code I used:

[image]

I couldn't use `with distinct` as it gave an error (F is clearly defined).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can put the command remove/detach form (f) at the end of your query.

```
match (n:Person)--(f:Form)
unwind f.names as nam
merge (n)-[:HAS_FORMS]-(:Form {names: nam})
detach delete f
```

Comment: this doesnt seem to work for me, it makes no changes

Answer (score 0):

In your second code block, you aren't bringing `f` along in the `with` statement.

```
match (n:person)--(f:form)
unwind f.names as nam
with distinct nam, f
detach delete f
merge (n)-[:HAS_FORMS]-(:form {names:nam})
```

I am unclear from your diagrams though. Do you want the nodes as `(:form)` or do you want the name property to be the label, e.g. `(:solid)`?

If you want the latter, you can use the `apoc.create.addLabels` procedure: https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.4/graph-updates/graph-refactoring/property-value-label/

Also, just a suggestion here, but you might think about using standard naming conventions for Neo4j. It makes your code more understandable.

Labels: MyLabel (caps for each word)

Properties: myProperty (caps for each word after the first)

Relationships: MY_RELATIONSHIP (all caps, underscores for spaces)

Answer (score 0):

You should only try to delete `f` only once (*before* you `UNWIND`). Also, a `WITH` clause eliminates any existing variables not specified by the clause.

This query should work:

```
MATCH (p:Person)-[:HAS_FORMS]->(f:Form)
WITH p, f, f.names AS names
DETACH DELETE f
WITH p, names
UNWIND names AS name
CREATE (p)-[:HAS_FORM]->(:Form {name: name})
```

Note that I changed the new relationship type to `HAS_FORM`, to make the name more accurate. But this would also allow you to re-run the query without touching the new relationships.